# What additive can I add to Jelly Wax/Gel Wax to increase its cooling time/setting time?

Tags: wax

Jelly Wax. Jelly wax, also commonly known as gel wax, is a clear, dimensionally stable, jelly-like material made from specially processed mineral oils. It can be used to create a variety of special effects and is also suitable for making decorative container candles. It is normally heated until it liquifies and then poured into a mould. It sets quickly back into a jelly.

I want to use it to pour into a transparent PVC pipe for a sculpture. Unfortunately I have found that it cools rather quickly for it to be useful for this purpose.

Anyone knows how I can increase the cooling time, using an additive maybe?

Answer (score 1):

At your own risk, you can try using plasticizers for waxes. Usually, these plasticizers are wax esters of palmitic acid (well-known example is spermaceti, which can be replaced with jojoba oil, or you can buy/obtain those esters). But it's hard to predict exact amount of plasticizer needed. Add too much - and it will be creamy I-will-never-cool substance. I hope we have chemical engineers here who know more about wax plasticizers and can add details to my superficial statement.

Comment: Thanks Kelly! The Jojoba seems to be working!

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Comment: You rock. Saved my ass :)

Comment: Sculptures are great, my favourite art form. I wish you good luck and creative successes :)

Comment: Thanks! Kelly btw do you know what else I can use besides Jojoba? It is a bit expensive, especially if I want to use this on a large scale

Comment: Any plasticizers for waxes. But as far as I know, for example, palmitic acid ester costs at least 5 d. per gramme. You can also try castor oil (such as for massage), it's pretty cheap (30-40 d. per liter),but I don't know whether it will be suitable for your wax.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the dimensions, the following may help. 
1. wrap the PVC with teflon tape.
2. coil nichrome wire around the pipe.
3. connect the ends to a power supply and slowly raise the voltage.
4. monitor the temperature of water in the PVC for testing.

Nichrome wire [data](http://wiretron.com/nichrome-resistance-wires/) will help you design a coil of a given resistance from which you can calculate the power dissipated. You should only try this if you have experience with basic electric, understand Ohm's law, etc.